# Watir Tables that is also a link

Tags: watir

I want to get the text field "test" out of this web page. How do i do it? I started with:

e.form(:name => "MainForm").table(.

and i tired a few things to get it to work but I an stuck. If it is unclear to what i am asking, just show be how to set a variable to the word "test".

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you might expect the page to change over time, there are a variety of ways.

If it is always the first cell of the page with class 'cellnohilite', you could do:

```
value = browser.td(:class, 'cellnohilite').text
```

If it is always the first cell of that specific table, you could do:

```
value = browser.tbody(:class, 'blacklabel').td.text
```

If you know that the text of the cell is 'Test', you could even do:

```
value = browser.td(:text, 'Test').text
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using Watir 1.6.5 and Watir 3.0.0 for different projects. `cell` is in 1.6.5. Assuming you are on the latest version, it should be `td`. Examples updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.frame(:name, "MainForm").td(:text, "Test").text
```

Good Luck!

Comment: The question was looking for how to get the word "Test". Using the exact cell text to locate the text defeats the purpose. Also it should be `browser.form` instead of `browser.frame`.